# Anyway to speed up the archiving of a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, archive

At midnight, I archive a SQL Server 2008 table by doing this in a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO archive(col1, col2....)
select col1, col2...
from tablename
where date <= @endDate

delete from tablename where date <= @enddate
```

Here is the table schema. I've changed the column names obviously. The archive table is exactly the same structure.

```
[col1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[col1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[col1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
```

The table typically has about 100,000 - 150,0000 rows with several indexes and is still having information written to it while I'm trying to perform this archive.

This process takes at the fastest, six minutes, and the slowest, 13 minutes.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: can you show the schema of the table?

Comment: Why not create partitions for this? It would be nearly instant. 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2780/archiving-sql-server-data-using-partitioning/

Comment: JW - schema has been added

Comment: While inserting and deleting the indexes of your table will be rebuild which can take time. You can disable indexes during that process and enable them afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partitioning is the fastest technique, but adds complexity and requires Enterprise Edition.

An alternate approach is to combine the DELETE and the INSERT into one statement by using the OUTPUT clause. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx. A DELETE with an OUTPUT clause is faster than individual INSERT/DELETE statements.

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
    OUTPUT DELETED.Col1, DELETED.col2, DELETED.col3 DELETED.col4 -- etc
    INTO archive ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
 WHERE date <= @enddate;
```

If you have issues with blocking due to the concurrent inserts, then you can batch the above statement by doing a loop:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 1 
WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE  top (1000) FROM tablename 
        OUTPUT DELETED.Col1, DELETED.col2, DELETED.col3 DELETED.col4 -- Eric
        INTO archive ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
    WHERE date <= @enddate  
    SET @i = @@rowcount
END
```

Additional note: There are a few restrictions for the output table.  It can't have triggers, be involved in foreign keys or have check constraints.

Comment: Oops, i did leave out the top ().   Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Added additional info on restrictions for target table.

Comment: I keep getting: "Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'."  I tried once with defining all the columns, and then a second time I just did OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO Archive and still get that syntax error.

Comment: I got it the WHERE clause in the delete needs to come AFTER the OUTPUT

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate way to handle archiving would be by creating and managing partitions.

There are several guides and tutorials available, such as:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/08/29/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-2-split-merge-and-switch-partitions.aspx